# How To Count comma, another cell Separated Values In all Column In Excel?

Tags: excel

I know this is a programming site so, sorry If It's not that place to ask this question... I don't know where can I ask that...

I have a column in Excel and in every cell I have a set of worlds that Separated by a comma.

How can I count and get an array  of the result of the count

for example in this column
[image]

My expected result is (Or something that look like that to be able to create a nice Graph)

[image]

Comment: countif not good enough?

Comment: @Jeeped  I don't want to be petty. But If I have a lot of wolds like 100? You know how to do it in one shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNTIF` with wildcards - something like this:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6,"*"&C2&"*")
```

[image]

Comment: This is really good for me for now, Thanks
Maybe you know a way to do it in one formula? and not times As many types of words?
For example if I have 1000 types of worlds?